# WPF Multilingual support from DB using XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am trying to extend my WPF application to have multilingual support from a Database.

My approach will use ResourceKeys to identify the content of each of the controls.

Creating this is MVVM was just a matter of of changing the properties to query the database with the resource and the selected language, as below:

```
    public string Example
    {
        get
        {
            if (SelectedLanguage == null)
                return string.Empty;

            return ControlMapping.getKey("MainWindow_TxtBoxExample", SelectedLanguage.LanguageID);
        }
    }
```

In an attempt to get the Bindings working I have set up a Converter which will take the key and select the appropriate value from the DB.

```
public class LanguageSupport : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ControlMapping.getKey(value.ToString(), SelectedLanguage.LanguageID);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then within the Window, I created a Static Resource to access the converter.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <LangSupport:LanguageSupport x:Key="ls"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Unfortunately this is were I get stuck...

I'm guessing that a converter isn't the correct way to go to populate the content for the various controls.

Many thanks in advance for any assistance you can give.

Comment: You have to specify your converter to every bindings you have, it will not be done automatically

Comment: I realize that, but its the how that is elusive part. When I initially started I coded <Label Name="ex3" Content="{Binding Path=ls}"/>, however this dosn't work.

Comment: You need to change binding by <Label Name="ex3" Content="{Binding Path=ls, Converter={StaticResource ls}}"/>, where ls is your converter key, according to you Window.Resources. However, if you use it in many Window, I suggest to put it in your App.Resources (on App.xaml)

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work. The content is empty and a breakpoint on the converter doesn't get hit.

Comment: The App resource would usually be my approach but due to project limitations its not an option.

Comment: Of course it won't works, I haven't see that you putting Path=ls. Is the Path=ls your converter or your value ? I suggest not using same name. And prefer using TextBlock to bind text if you want to display text only

Answer (score 0):

I included a reference to the mscorlib to give access to the String class.

```
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Then I defined a resource which i can use to assign to a control.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <LangSupport:LanguageSupport x:Key="ls"/>
    <sys:String x:Key="hardccodedstring">MainWindow.hardcodedstring</sys:String>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then within the control itself I altered the bindings to use the string as a ConverterParamater.

```
<Label Name="ex3" Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ls}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource hardccodedstring}}"/>
```

The converter itself also needed changed to use this parameter, rather than the value.

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (parameter == null)
            return string.Empty;

        return ControlMapping.getKey(parameter.ToString(), SelectedLanguage.LanguageID);
    }
```

Comment: Using a converter is an extremely clunky way of doing this. A ResourceManager is simply a static class that looks stuff up in the resource file - you could create your own ResourceManager that retrieves from a database instead.